# Is there a way to set the output of an AppleScript to a certain color, and change depending on conditions?

Tags: macos, colors, applescript

I have a functioning script that looks at the activity state in a specific app, and time spent in that state, then shows it in the status bar of macOS. It works as expected, but I'd like to add some coloring so that if you go over a certain amount of time in a certain state, the text will turn yellow or red. For example, I might be in the Idle status for 8 minutes, which shows in the status bar, but when it reaches 10 minutes, I'd like for the text to change from white to red.

I've done some research on the 'attribute range' function, but I'm unsure of how that might be applied (or if it can be applied) to my script since I'm not working with text in Pages, Microsoft Word, Text Edit, or something similar, just a value that is returned to the status bar.

```
on idle
    -- Update the status item's text here.
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists process appName) then
            display alert "Application " & appName & " is not running" as warning giving up after 6
            quit me
        end if
        tell process appName
            -- assume the window and toolbar are always going to be there
            repeat until exists of first window's first toolbar's fourth group's first group's first menu button
                delay 0.2
            end repeat
            tell first window's first toolbar's fourth group's first group's first menu button
                set activityState to first item of (value as list) as text
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell

    set statusItem's button's title to activityState

    (*
      The return value gives the time in seconds
    *)
    return 1
end idle
```

I'm wondering if I can use a command to set the 'activityState' attribute to a certain color since that variable has been defined to the appropriate area of that affected app's GUI, then to set conditions for that to change depending on the type of activity state, and time spent there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An [attributed string](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring) can be used for the status item title:

```
set greenAttr to current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithObjects:{current application's NSColor's greenColor()} forKeys:{current application's NSForegroundColorAttributeName}
set redAttr to current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithObjects:{current application's NSColor's redColor()} forKeys:{current application's NSForegroundColorAttributeName}

set attrText to current application's NSMutableAttributedString's alloc's initWithString:"whatever"
attrText's setAttributes:greenAttr range:{0, attrText's |length|()}
statusItem's button's setAttributedTitle:attrText
```

Then at some point the attributes can be changed or replaced and the title set with the new attributed string:

```
if elapsedTime > someTime then attrText's setAttributes:redAttr range:{0, attrText's |length|()}
statusItem's button's setAttributedTitle:attrText
```

Comment: Thanks! I can tell this is what I'm looking for. To clarify, would `current application` end up being `appName` or the actual name of the program I'm working within? Also, when it makes the call to `set attrText to current applications's NSMutableAttributedString's alloc's...`, could I just replace the string at the end with the name of the variable I've established, which is `activityState`?

Comment: Yes, you can set the string used by `initWithString` to whatever you want.
`current application` is an object specifier that refers to the current AppleScript environment that is running the script, it isn’t the name of the application.  This is the environment that all the AppleScriptObjC bits are defined in, so it is used to reference the various classes, methods, constants, etc.  If you want to make a shortcut or whatever, you can set a property, for example `property thisApp : current application` - just be careful if sharing code, as the shortcut may not be declared in other scripts.

Comment: @red_menace Thank you for clearing that up! I was able to get it to work by using `...alloc's initWithString:activityState`. It wasn't taking when I tried using the `statusItem` variable. I'll play around with the next line to change the attributes based on the amount of time spent in the activity state next. I wanted to run one more question by you; would I edit the range in the following line to change the color from light green to something darker? `attrText's setAttributes:greenAttr range:{0, attrText's |length|()}`

Comment: The range doesn’t have anything to do with color, it is about the range of characters the attribute is applied to.  You might take a look at using `NSColor’s systemGreenColor`, it is a little darker.   I’ve also updated the [script I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57437805/10853463) in your previous topic to include font and color changes, if you wanted to take a look at that.