# How Can I Show Progress/Countdown to Next Action In The Menubar Systemwide Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I created an Applescript that every 600 seconds retrieve the last line of a log file and add it to a Google Sheet spreadsheet.

This is extremely useful, but it is starting to annoy me not knowing when the next action will be performed.

So now I'm trying to display the progress (or countdown in seconds) to the next action in the menubar, so I can, kind of, be aware that the focus application will change.

Can please someone point me in the right direction?

--- Added Information ---

Now, instead of showing a countdown, I want to just simply show how many steps left, and it's still not working. This is a test code I'm working on:

```
set progress total steps to 12
set progress completed steps to 0
set progress description to "Running..."
set progress additional description to "ETA: 120 Seconds"

repeat with a from 1 to 12
    delay 10
    set progress completed steps to a
    set ETA to a * 10
    set progress additional description to "ETA: " & ETA & " seconds"
end repeat
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Without seeing what you have done so far, perhaps something in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421381) will give you an idea.

Comment: @red_menace, hey, thanks for your answer. I have edited the question a little bit, and also added a test code I'm trying to make work.

Thanks!

Comment: Your added test script seems to run OK, what is "not working"?

Comment: @red_menace, thanks again for your reply! :)

Well, wasn't I supposed to see the progress by click the icon in the menubar? The code itself works, but I can't see how many steps left, percentage completed, etc.

Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sz1i4ma81s19adh/Screenshot%202020-05-11%2011.21.05.png?dl=0

Comment: There wasn't an indication that your script was being used in an Automator **Run AppleScript** action.  In an Automator workflow the status item (gear) indicates the number of individual actions in the workflow that have been completed.  The commands you are using in your test script apply in a regular AppleScript, although there won't be a status item in the menubar unless you are running it from the Scripts Menu.

Comment: @red_menace, thanks and sorry about the missing information. I'm using the code on an Automator Application. In that case, it's not possible to show progress/status in the menubar, correct?

Comment: Well, if you are looking for progress at a finer level than just when each action in the workflow completes, you would need to use your own status item to provide it, so you might as well go with an AppleScript (or Xcode) application, which can show a status item in the menubar.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link red_menace gave in comments and the screenshot you provided, here's a script that (I think) will give the results you want. It's not an automator workflow. This is an AppleScript stay-open application. Copy it into Script Editor and save is as an application: choose "Application" from the `File Format` pulldown menu on the save screen, and make sure you check the `Stay open after run handler` checkbox. then run the application like normal and see the demo.

```
use framework "AppKit"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

property ca : current application
property NSStatusBar : class "NSStatusBar"
property NSMenu : class "NSMenu"
property NSMenuItem : class "NSMenuItem"
property NSImage : class "NSImage"
property NSProgressIndicator : class "NSProgressIndicator"
property NSView : class "NSView"
property NSTextField : class "NSTextField"

property idle_time : 1
global status_bar_item, progress_views, idx

on run
    set progress_views to {}
    set status_bar_item to NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar's statusItemWithLength:(ca's NSSquareStatusItemLength)
    set status_bar_item's |menu| to NSMenu's alloc's initWithTitle:""
    set status_bar_item's |menu|'s minimumWidth to 220
    my setImage(ca's NSImageNameSmartBadgeTemplate)
    my addToStatusMenu(my progress_view_obj("Number 1"))
    my addToStatusMenu(my progress_view_obj("Number 2"))
    set idx to 0
end run

on idle
    set idx to idx + 1
    repeat with this_obj in progress_views
        set rand_numb to (random number from 1 to 9)
        (this_obj's progress_indicator's incrementBy:rand_numb)
        this_obj's changeLabel("Adding: " & rand_numb)
    end repeat
    if idx > 20 then
        quit
    end if
    return idle_time
end idle

on quit
    -- remove status item and quit
    NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar's removeStatusItem:status_bar_item
    continue quit
end quit

on addToStatusMenu(obj)
    set statusMenu to status_bar_item's |menu|
    statusMenu's addItem:(obj's menu_item)
    set end of progress_views to obj
end addToStatusMenu

on progress_view_obj(label_value)
    script prog_view_obj
        -- text field
        property progress_indicator : missing value
        property menu_item : missing value
        property label_field : missing value

        global content_view

        -- make label field
        set label_field to NSTextField's labelWithString:label_value
        set label_field's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false

        -- progress indicator
        set progress_indicator to NSProgressIndicator's alloc's initWithFrame:(ca's NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 20))
        set progress_indicator's indeterminate to false
        progress_indicator's setStyle:(ca's NSProgressIndicatorStyleBar)
        progress_indicator's startAnimation:me
        set progress_indicator's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false

        -- content view for menu item
        set content_view to NSView's alloc's initWithFrame:(ca's NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 100))
        set content_view's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false
        content_view's addSubview:label_field
        content_view's addSubview:progress_indicator

        -- constraints to arrange elements
        --set view_height_constraint to content_view's heightAnchor's constraintEqualToConstant:100
        --view_height_constraint's setActive:true
        set lf_left_margin to content_view's leadingAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(label_field's leadingAnchor) |constant|:-10
        lf_left_margin's setActive:true
        set pi_left_margin to content_view's leadingAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(progress_indicator's leadingAnchor) |constant|:-10
        pi_left_margin's setActive:true
        set pi_right_margin to content_view's trailingAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(progress_indicator's trailingAnchor) |constant|:10
        pi_left_margin's setActive:true
        set top_spacing_const to content_view's topAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(label_field's topAnchor) |constant|:-10
        set mid_spacing_const to label_field's bottomAnchor's constraintEqualToAnchor:(progress_indicator's topAnchor) |constant|:-10
        set bott_spacing_const to content_view's bottomAnchor's constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToAnchor:(progress_indicator's bottomAnchor) |constant|:10
        top_spacing_const's setActive:true
        mid_spacing_const's setActive:true
        bott_spacing_const's setActive:true
        content_view's updateConstraints()

        -- create and flesh out menu item
        set menu_item to NSMenuItem's alloc's init()
        set menu_item's view to content_view
        content_view's updateConstraints()

        on changeLabel(label_value)
            set label_field's stringValue to label_value
        end changeLabel

        on changeMinValue(val)
            set progress_indicator's minValue to val
        end changeMinValue

        on changeMaxValue(val)
            set progress_indicator's maxValue to val
        end changeMaxValue

        on changeValue(val)
            set progress_indicator's doubleValue to val
        end changeValue

        on currentValue()
            return progress_indicator's doubleValue() as integer
        end currentValue
    end script

    run prog_view_obj
    return prog_view_obj
end progress_view_obj

on setImage(imageName)
    status_bar_item's button's setImageScaling:(ca's NSImageScaleProportionallyDown)
    status_bar_item's button's setImage:(NSImage's imageNamed:imageName)
    status_bar_item's button's setImagePosition:(ca's NSImageLeft)
end setImage
```

You shouldn't need to change anything except in the `run` and `idle` handlers — the first to set up the menus and the second to increment the progress bars or update the labels as needed. You can change how frequently the indicators update by increasing or decreasing the `idle-time` property (it's currently set to run the idle loop once a second). You'll only need to get into the big, messy handler if you need to change the layout or size of the menu items.

Technical point: I've put each progress view inside a script object (`script prog_view_obj`) to make it easier to work with. That may take some time for you to wrap your head around — it's tricky AppleScript — but at any rate, there's a bunch of convenience handlers at the end of the script object definition that you may find useful.